# Uncaught Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains NaN in property

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

Receiving this error when I try adding an expense to the firebase database:

```
Uncaught Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains NaN in property 'users.mzsNqPucvWZMWuyo4sThlMqyR1k2.expenses.km'
```

at **Validation.js** and **react-dom.development.js**

Getting a firebase warning too.

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/mzsNqPucvWZMWuyo4sThlMqyR1k2/expenses/-LAsp1j0HVUP-1Y32UMd failed: permission_denied
```

And then the promise is catching a permission denied even though I have set .read and .write rules to true in firebase rules.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
    at Repo.js:527
```

Code snippets that might help. STill don't know how to get rid of permission denied.

**Firebase rules for reference:**

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
      "users": {
        "$user_id": {
          ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
            "expenses": {
              "$expense_id": {
                ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['title', 'amount', 'details', 'createdAt', 'category', 'km'])",
                  "title": {
                    ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"
                  },
                  "amount": {
                    ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
                  },
```

**Expense add action (redux)**

```
const {
            title = '',
            details = '',
            amount = 0,
            createdAt = 0,
            category = '',
            km = 0
        } = expenseData;
        const expense = { title, details, amount, createdAt, category, km };
        database.ref(`users/${uid}/expenses`).push(expense).then((ref) => {
            dispatch(addExpense({
                id: ref.key,
                ...expense
            }));
        });
```

I get this error when I submit the form so I'll include it.

**Add Exp**

```
export class AddExp extends React.Component {
    onSubmit = (expense) => {
        this.props.startAddExp(expense);
        this.props.history.push('/');
    };
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <ExpenseForm 
                path={this.props.location.pathname}
                onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Expense form onSubmit()**

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.title || !this.state.amount) {
        this.setState(() => ({ error: 'Error'}))
    } else {
        this.setState(() => ({ error: 'error' }));
        this.props.onSubmit({
            title: this.state.title,
            amount: parseFloat(this.state.amount, 10) * 100,
            createdAt: this.state.createdAt.valueOf(),
            details: this.state.details,
            category: this.state.category,
            km: parseFloat(this.state.km, 10) * 100
        });
    }
   };
```

I don't think it is code related, seems more like firebase is preventing the insertion.

Answer (score 1):

If validation rules fail, they still send back a `PERMISSION DENIED` error. I would double check your validation rules to make sure they cover edge cases, such as when `title` is `''` (fails since `newData.val().length` is `0` and not `> 0`). You have already tested this in your answer by removing the validation rules ([which don't cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-validation)). Feel free to post the rest of your rules and examples of what is failing and why it shouldn't.

Comment: I will try it out and get back with answer

Answer (score 0):

The error went away when I changed the rules in firebase to just read & write.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
}
```

But I still do not understand what was wrong with my previous ruleset but this will work for now.